# Fragment doesn't start Service

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, service, fragment

I'm coding an app with a ViewPager and I'm using Fragments for that. Everything works fine (Like I want to).

One of my Fragments in the ViewPager has a Button which starts a Service.

`getActivity().startService(new Intent(getActivity(),Service.class))` is the code from the Button.

Now when I'm clicking the Button nothing happens. Is there another solution for that?

Let me know if you need more information and code.

Thanks for help.

Comment: have you registered service in your `manifest.xml` ?

Comment: Do you register the service in `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: Also, have you set the appropriate listener to your `Button`?

Comment: well, yes I have. But now I see my fault. I renamed it 1 week ago. And I didn't change it in the `manifest.xml` ..... Thank you for that "momentum"

Comment: Also use the application context to start a service that probably will outlive activity's context: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getApplicationContext%28%29

Answer (score 8):

1) IN MANIFEST DECLARE SERVICE:

```
<service android:name=".GameService" />
```

2) NEXT WRITE CLASS WITCH EXTENDS SERVICE: (in my example it is Intent Serivce)

```
public class GameService extends IntentService
{
public GameService()
    {
        super("GameService");
    }

   @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
    {
       ..do some background work...
     }
}
```

3) MY FRAGMENT WITH BROADCAST RECEIVER AND CODE WITH CALLING SERVICE:

```
public class Stats_Fragment extends Fragment
{
 BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

            if(extras!=null)
            {
               //for example: extras.getString("value");
             }
        }
     }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_stats, container, false);

        //CALLING SERIVCE (I call it here but you can call somewhere else...

         Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), GameService.class);
         intent.putExtra("Intent_Action", 3);
         intent.putExtra("playerID", MainClass.loggedUserID);
         getActivity().startService(intent);
    } 

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getActivity().registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(GameService.NOTIFICATION));
        CallStatsService();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        getActivity().unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }

 }
```

I hope it will help:)

Answer (score 2):

This is nearly always related to not registering the Service into the manifest. Happens to me all the time. Just put 
`<service android:name="your.package.name.YourService"/`>
into your manifest.